# Comparing the declared function, and a FunctionObject, why does the latter can console the global variance(same variance name declared inside)?

Tags: javascript

I could not figure out this question, so I'll ask in StackOverflow for the first time.
In the code below, func1() first consoled "scope" as undefined, which makes sense to me, as "scope" is declared inside the function, which is yet uninitialized.
However, I coded the exact same contents in the function object, and it consoled "global", which was declared outside the function.
**I want to know why the outputs differ.**
Code:

```js
'use strict';
var scope = "global";

function func1() {
  console.log(scope); //scope == undefined
  var scope = "local";
  console.log(scope); //scope == local
}
func1();
var func2 = new Function();
func2() 
{
  console.log(scope); //scope == global <--why???
  var scope = "local";
  console.log(scope); //scope == local
}
```

Terminal:

```
undefined
local
global
local
```

Comment: That code throws a syntax error. It doesn't give the result you claim.

Comment: In your second example, you're creating a function `func2`, calling it `func2()` and then creating a block. The `{}` isn't a function body so the `var` isn't function scoped like it is in the first example